# C2DM: only registered Google account receives messages from server

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I seem to be stuck spending hours of trying to figure out what goes wrong. It feels as I am misunderstanding something entirely. So here's the thing:

While trying to make C2DM work, I 1st signed up at Google's C2DM service with a dedicated email adress. That's the one I want to use to send messages from the server to the clients. Then I added code to the client app and registered the device for C2DM. The obtained registration id is sent to the server and stored in the db.

The problem arises when I try to send messages (no matter if I use `curl`or php) to the devices. Sending to account that I used to signup to the C2DM service in the 1st place works flawlessly. However, sending to any other device fails with 
`Error=NotRegistered`. And I just don't get why. I am using the `auth key` from the signup account and the `registration id` that I create from the clients. I've (re)-created the `registration id` like hundreds of times but according to the google code page 
`Error=NotRegistered` means that the `registration_id` is not valid.

*Attempt of clarification:*

*I can perfectly send messages to the registration ID that is linked to the google account I used to sign up to C2DM. All other attempts of sending messages to different registration IDs fail. So I can basically send messages to a single registration ID.*

*Maybe I should be checking my understanding of C2DM: is the server limited to sending messages to a single device? I thought the server could send messages to each device that has submitted its registration id...*

What am I missing/misunderstanding?

Thanks a million, Steff

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You say "Sending to account that I used to signup to the C2DM service in the 1st place works flawlessly" but you don't send anything to this account, you send messages to a registration ID. Can you please clarify exactly what you are doing, and what works and what doesn't, because I've read your question four times and it's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: Sure, I'll try to clarify. I was already expecting this. Sorry for the mess...

Answer (score 2):

There's no limitation on which devices it sends to. What's more likely is that the registration ID you're sending to is wrong, or the device you're sending to has not successfully registered.

I would suggest double checking the registration ID, test on another device if you can, make sure when you submit the message to Google's servers you are getting a 200 response, and confirm that the devices are definitely successfully registering to receive C2DM messages.

I'd suggest reading this too. It's the best tutorial on C2DM I've seen.
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Comment: That's exactly the tutorial that I've followed. Moreover, I've tried 3 different accounts on several devices. Just for my understanding: the auth_key is (once obtained) a) only for the server account and 'static' (in that sense that there is only a single one). Registration IDs are per account. That is, each account that submitted their registration ID SHOULD be able to receive messages via C2DM. Correct?

Comment: One more thing: according to http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#push I am indeed receiving a positive server response (200). The error code, however, persists.

Comment: I think you've understood it correct. There's one auth code, and it's used to authenticate you sending a message to Google's C2DM servers. The registration ID is a destination - representing that particular app on that particular device. I assume the package names on all devices are the same? Each auth code is specific to an app's package name. Does your broadcast receiver receive anything from C2DM after the registration confirmation?

Comment: You said "the error code, however, persists". What error code, and where?

Comment: The error code that I receive in response from the C2DM server. It says "Error=NotRegistered". I am always addressing the same package name and obtained the auth key for that package name. There is, however, a little more light now. It seems to be a device issue. I've added another account to a Nexus 1. It is now able receive messages for both accounts. Other devices like a Desire Z or SGS unfortunately fail. And I somehow refuse to believe that this is a device issue...

Comment: Meanwhile I am able to send a message to the C2DM server which does not report any error. The message, however, is not delivered to the according device (Desire Z).

Comment: C2DM requires that the device has Market installed, which though devices do, and also that the user is signed into the Google account. Is it possible the Google Account isn't signed into on them?

you said the C2DM server returns "Error=NotRegistered" but you also said "I am able to send a message to the C2DM server, which does not report an error". Is the C2DM server reporting an error, or not?

Comment: When I asked my initial question I received a message on 1 account while 2 others failed with "Error=NotRegistered". After adding a 2nd account to the Nexus it went flawlessly for those 2 accounts (3rd still responding with "Error=NotRegistered"). After removing account 2 from the N1 and restoring it on the Desire Z, it didn't report that error but also does not deliver the message.So I end up with 3 accounts on 3 devices: 1 receiving perfectly (N1), 1 not receiving and no error, and 1 not receiving with "Error=NotRegistered"

Comment: Btw: I've always re-registered the devices and updated the registration_id on the server

Comment: Board asked me to [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3091/discussion-between-steff-and-ollie-c)

Answer (score 1):

There is token information in serverside code that allows to chose which devise you want to send a message, have you changed this token (to another device's token) when you want to send a message to another device?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the future: 'data in the background' (phone config) was disabled. Turning it On solved the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you will always need to use the account you have used to setup the c2dm when registering the client.

You will need to make sure the client phone has a Google account active on the phone (doesn't matter which), but then when you register you need to use the same account that you used to register the app. I think it is used as some type of identifier to know which server should be able to send notifications to the app. An identifier of the phone is probably retrieved from the context by Google. An identifier of the phone for your server should be created by your app (which could be the locally active Google account).

Comment: thanks for your answer but that does not really answer my question. I think I did all of what you suggested. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

let's say that you have signed up for C2DM with the email 'foo@foo.com'.

Subsequently, you request for a registration ID in your app itself. The reason why you are only able to send push notifications to the registration ID associated with 'foo@foo.com', is because you are supposed to request for registration IDs *only* with the e-mail address you provided when you signed up for C2DM.

Does this solve your query?