# Android GCM Retrieve RegistrationID

Tags: android

I am trying to retrieve my GCM registration ID from my android emulator but when i debug the program crashes.
This is my MainActivity code:

```
  try {
       GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);       //  <-- Crashes here
       GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
       final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
       if (regId.equals("")) 
       {
         GCMRegistrar.register(this,Sender_ID);
       }
       else
       {
         Log.v("Registrationnnnnn", "Already registered");
       }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       Log.e("ErrorHAi",e.getMessage());
   }
```

I've read that this line checks if the device support GCM.But I've installed Google Cloud Messaging from SDK Manager extras. I've also installed

Android SDK Tools : rev 20
Android SDK Platform Tools : rev 12
Android 4.1 Api 16

When I mention

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

this in my manifest file it runs but crashes as I've mentioned in the above code.But if I change the targetSdkVersion to xx as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app) it says Install_Failed_OLDER_SDK.

I am currently running this application on  Android 4.1 API level 16.

**Update:**

My Logcat:

```
07-03 20:34:25.878: E/Trace(906): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-03 22:30:57.748: E/Trace(1016): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.pack.gcm.MyBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pack.gcm.MyBroadcastReceiver
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2210)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pack.gcm.MyBroadcastReceiver
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2205)
07-03 22:31:01.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     ... 10 more
```

Now I don't know why it is giving such errors although I've installed all the prerequisites.

Comment: Can you provide the Logcat logs?

Comment: have you added required Manifest stuff as mentioned in http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html ?

Comment: try to configure your build path to include the libraries , I mean you sometimes have to ensure the library is checked in Build path configuration

Comment: oh thnx alot for your help Muhannad I've solved the problem.Actually my BroadcastReciever and IntentService classes were not instintiating correctly.I found out when I posted you the logcat :) Thnx again for your help.

Comment: Ok , nice !!! But it was discussing you too!!! hope you the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly Android G2DM not supporting Android emulator because it is basically depends on that the device has a google account , and the android emulators doesn't have such an account so when it try to register the device , it doesn't find the required google account  to complete registration  take a look at [c2dm-only-registered-google-account-receives-messages-from-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271653/c2dm-only-registered-google-account-receives-messages-from-server)

Comment: i am using gcm not c2dm does that make any difference? and google have given examples at developer.android.com so i think it means that it does support.

Comment: I read the link you gave there he successfully retrieved the regID.But I am stuck at the first line and not able to retrieve the regID.